# ContentTemplate selection based upon the DataContext in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, datatemplate

In my Master/detail scenario, I have a datagrid as master and a UserControl as child.
When a particular Row being selected in master grid I assign it to the UserControl's DataContext.
In my User Control I have couple of DataTemplates as Resources and ContentControl as the Child Container. What I'm struggling with is how to dynamically select the ContentTemplate of ContentControl based upon the UserControl's DataContext's property TemplateName.

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource ????}}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: See update on my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For SL [here is the link on Silverlight DataTemplateSelector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx) which should be useful to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have used the following code as my control is COntentControl and I cannot use the ItemTemplateSelector property in it and it still does not work.
public class MyDataTemplateSelector:ContentControl
{protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
{ base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
 if (newContent != null)
    {
      Product p = newContent as Product;
    if (p != null)
     {
       ContentTemplate = this.Resources["Product1"] as DataTemplate;
     }
   }
 }
Any idea what's wrong

Comment: The idea is in TemplateSelector. Each entity linked with datatemplates has a TemplateSelector, for example, for ItemsControl it is ItemTemplateSelector, in your case it is a ContentTemplateSelector.

Link below provide full info on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx

Comment: Well the ContentControl does not have the property called ContentTemplateSelector. When I set that Property, I get the error invalid property.

Comment: THis is what I get in output window
System.Windows.Data Error: 'MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Project.MyDataTemplateSelector' (type 'Project.MyDataTemplateSelector'); BindingExpression: Path='' DataItem='Project.MyDataTemplateSelector' (HashCode=24111608); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl' (Name='TicketView'); target property is 'ContentTemplate' (type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate').. System.InvalidOperationException: Can't convert type Project.MyDataTemplateSelector to type System.Windows.DataTemplate.

Comment: You're may be doing something wrong, because if you use really ContentControl class it HAS ContentTemplateSelector property, which marked with BindableProperty attribute.

Comment: MyDataTemplateSelector must bee inherited from DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: I belive that this Property is available in WPF and not in Silverlight

Comment: Wait some time, I'll try to implement and post to you sources.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx

Check this link. I have replicated this and it works. You need to refine it for your needs. Properties (BrazilTemplate, UsaTemplate) you can obtain from resources by using TryFindResource. Identify what template to use by using either item or containter parameters.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I 'll have a look into this and come back to U.
In the meantime, I wonder if you could help me in another issue.
As I said that this usercontrol is embebded on a page who has the datagrid. In this user control I'm displaying the dataForm. When I edit an item in this control in DataForm and save it, the changes reflect in the datagrid but my datagrid gets frozen and I cannot move to different pages. my datapager becomes disable as well.
Any idea what's going wrong there

Comment: You have to trace all chain of runtime after saving edited item and figure out where it frozes your datagrid. It's unclear for me now to understand. As I may suppose your project is commercial, binded to your own database and you can't give me any source code, am I right?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't give U the code.
BUT I think this is just a simple scnario of Master Details.
I just found that I cannot access the DataTemplates in the code behind file which are defined in the UserContorl.Resources section locally. I have to move them in the Resource dictionary of either external file or App.xaml Resources section. Which took me back to the Point 0 because I cannot use the code behind for them.
On Main Page I want to have a datagrid as Master.
and then I need to customise the Details section based upon the Item Type selected in the grid and write custom code4them

Comment: I downvoted because there is no ContentTemplateSelector property in Silverlight, so the answer in its current form is completely wrong. Please edit and add the only useful link in this conversation, which is the one to codeproject.com and I will be happy to upvote instead!